# Why did Lister bother painting Red Dwarf?

Tags: red-dwarf

The *Red Dwarf* opening sequence shows somebody - [presumably Lister](https://www.reddit.com/r/RedDwarf/comments/163063/whos_the_one_painting_the_ship/) - painting the ship. This seems bizarre. Everything about Lister's character suggests a predisposition towards laziness. He likes to cut corners; he is not the model professional. Yet painting the exterior of Red Dwarf is an infinitely arduous and time-consuming task.

**Why could he be smegged?**

Comment: Because it's funny!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In [Stasis Leak](http://www.ladyofthecake.com/rdscripts/season2/Stasisle.txt), first episode of Series II, we saw Captain Hollister sentencing Lister, and later Rimmer, to "PD", or Punishment Detail. Rimmer describes it thusly

> **RIMMER:** *Why didn't you tell the Captain this?*
>
> **LISTER:** *What?  And get someone into trouble?*
>
> **RIMMER:** *Oh, no.  **Eight weeks painting the smegging ship?***
>
> **LISTER:** *I'm sorry.*
>
> **RIMMER:** *Get the space-suits.*

What we saw in the opening was someone on PD, probably in order to show the scale of the ship.

Comment: You may want to point out that this was prior to everyone being dead, Dave.

Comment: @Valorum Everyone's dead? What about Petersen?

Comment: @DCShannon - Everyone's dead, Dave. Everyone.

Comment: It's just too bad for the dustpile crew that they didn't get their ashes spread on the backwards planet. Too bad indeed.

Comment: @Valorum - Wait, are you trying to tell me that *everyone's* dead?

Comment: @Juled. - Dave. Dead. Everone.  Is.