# Why are stormtroopers stationed outside the Death Star near the turbolaser batteries adjacent to Bay 327?

Tags: star-wars, death-star, stormtroopers

[Comments in another question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/148054/has-darth-vader-ever-been-exposed-to-the-vacuum-of-space/148066#comment379665_148066) led me to this image from *A New Hope*:

[image: Millenium Falcon entering Bay 327]

Why are stormtroopers walking around outside near the turbolaser batteries? What is there to guard or patrol in the cold vacuum of space? Are they doing an exterior patrol?

These appear to be regular stormtroopers. Maybe there is an extra pack suggestive of an EVA (Extravehicular Activity) shown.

Comment: No clue as to why they feel the need for exterior guards, but they'd have one hell of a view from their post :-)

Comment: cigarette break?

Comment: Isn't that bay near the Death Star's equator. Shouldn't Artificial Gravity point towards the center of the station? The Falcon and the Stormtroopers don't seem to think so,

Comment: @CrazyDino not sure how well that would work in vacuum.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer I'd guess the artificial gravity comes from the deck plates or something.

Comment: What's an EVA?
Environmental ... ...?  http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/EVA

Comment: @Pysis second row: "Extravehicular Activity - NASA". The term is also commonly (incorrectly?) used to refer to the suit NASA astronauts wear when leaving a space shuttle.

Comment: @terdon where there's a will, there's a way.

Comment: @CrazyDino where's there's a will, there's EVA?

Comment: @DavidTonhofer: "The Falcon and the Stormtroopers don't seem to think so" - not to mention the huge landing bays such as the one the Falcon is approaching.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

### They're Spacetroopers

They were <s>retconned</s> identified as such at Celebration Anaheim 2015, and got a [collectible toy release](http://www.sideshowtoy.com/collectibles/star-wars-spacetrooper-hot-toys-902381/) from Hot Toys; quoting from their description:

> The Spacetroopers are assigned to operate in Zero-G environments, and true Star Wars fans will see these troopers making their appearance when the Millennium Falcon was first captured by the Death Star.
>
> *[...]*
>
> This specialized trooper features a beautifully crafted armor and helmet, a highly detailed Spacetrooper rebreather pack with detachable parts, two types of blasters, and a specially designed figure stand.

Unfortunately, there's no mention of what they expect to find while patrolling the outside of a space station. For all we know, they're [painting the hull](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/147574/31051).

Comment: Where else are you gonna station a trooper who pissed off the Sergeant or god forbid, the Major? No Alaska on Death Star... but there is outer space, all cold-like.

Comment: @DVK-in-exile I'm guessing the two in that picture walked in on Tarkin and [Admiral Daala](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Natasi_Daala#Wilhuff_Tarkin)

Comment: @DVK-in-exile space is not [cold as Alaska](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SpaceIsCold) :P

Comment: Gotta check the hull for Mynocks or Space Harpies!

Comment: Marketing guy: "Mr. Lucas, we have an issue, we have thousands of stormtrooper toys in stock and nobody is buying them anymore!". G. Lucas: "Mmmm... I see... Oh well, it ain't no stormtrooper! These are spacetroopers! Get them rebranded as such and I will make an statement for `true Star Wars fan`". Marketing guy: "You are a genius, Mr Lucas. Have you ever considered a job in marketing?" Mr Lucas "I would not know what to do at marketing at all..."

Comment: Maybe they are there just in case to shoot at whatever troops/infiltrators the Millenium Falcon could drop before entering the hangar?

Answer (score 27):

As mentioned elsewhere, these are [spacetroopers](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Spacetrooper). There are all sorts of threats that could be spotted outside a space station, “in the cold vacuum of space,” and potentially effectively combated by stormtroopers:

- Spacefaring animals, such as the [purrgil](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Purrgil). These probably wouldn’t pose an existential threat to a station as big as the Death Star, but could probably fly in and harass troopers, damage weapons, and so forth.
- Space-faring droids used as weapons. [Buzz droids](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Pistoeka_sabotage_droid) would be a particular threat, with the potential to destroy important installations, as demonstrated in the Rebel attack on the Star Destroyer *Perilous*.

  > Two vultures headed directly for the shield generator. He destroyed
  >   one and then another, but the buzz droids they carried floated out of
  >   the fire of the vultures’ destruction, glommed on to the shield
  >   generator, and there exploded into flame.
  >
  > <sub>*Lords of the Sith*</sub>

  The enemies of the Empire could even be employing leftover [rocket battle droids](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/B1-series_rocket_battle_droid), perhaps.
- Even humans in space suits might be able to move along the outside of the ship, and potentially damage weapons or infiltrate the battle station.

Comment: You may want to mention the real Earth military equivalent of eyeball guarding against saboteures in diving suits by the Navy

Comment: Let's not forget that they might be able to spot ships attached to the hull in radar blindspots.

Comment: It could also be a form of training or drill. The military loves to have idle troops doing pointless tasks.

Answer (score 24):

This scene is taken wholesale from the Ralph McQuarrie concept art seen below:

[image: Death Star Concept]

In the concept art, troopers in black armor, presumably pressurized space suits similar to those of Darth Vader and TIE Pilots, stand in for the Stormtroopers / Spacetroopers seen in the final film.

Perhaps Stormtrooper extras were easier to source when filming.

In-(concept)-universe, these black-suited units are easier to imagine as Turbolaser Engineers and Death Star Trench Maintenance Staff than the military Stormtroopers seen in the final film. Perhaps they're even independent contractors.

[After all,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iQdDRrcAOjA)

> "Do you think the average Stormtrooper knows how to [repair a Turbolaser]? All they know is killing and white uniforms."

Answer (score 14):

They’re there to provide scale in the film, otherwise there wouldd be no way to tell if the “ceiling” in that shot was 20cm or 20m above their heads.

Comment: The Millennium Falcon provides scale, and the ceiling directly above the stormtroopers, which are closer in the foreground, is out of the shot.

Comment: @Random832 - The Falcon is in the distance and you can't judge the size of the turbolasers from it.  The stormtroopers are close to them and show that they're ******* huge!